# NoMethodError using has_selector for rspec

Tags: testing, rspec, capybara

These are my tests:

```
it "should have the title 'Contact'" do

  visit '/static_pages/contact'

  expect(page).to have_title("Rails Development | Contact")

end



it "should have 'h1'" do

  visit '/static_pages/contact'

  expect(page).to has_selector?('h1')

end
```

why the first test works normally but the second one gives me NoMethodError?

1)

```
Static Pages Contact page should have 'h1'

 Failure/Error:expect(page).to has_selector?('h1')

 NoMethodError:

   undefined method `matches?' for true:TrueClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSpec method `to` expects a RSpec `Matcher`, but you've passed it the results of `has_selector` which, if it succeeds, is `true`, thus resulting in the error you're getting.

The Capybara method `has_selector?` is intended to be used implicitly by the RSpec matcher `have_selector` as in:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('h1')
```

See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#querying for more information.

Comment: I am still confused but somehow get it working now. The following seems to be working.    expect(page).to have_selector('h1')

Comment: I have to remove the question mark and use 'have' instead of 'has'. I looked at the jnicklas documentation but still don't understand their relations.

Comment: `has_selector?` is a simple predicate that returns true or false.  `have_selector` is an RSpec `Matcher` which is what the RSpec `to` method requires to be passed to it.  The latter is implemented on top of the former.

Comment: I just realized I had inadvertently included the `?` at the end of `have_selector` in the code sample in the first version of my answer, although I had it correct in the body.  Sorry about that. I've updated the code sample.